# How to display text through ajax in asp.net by using $(document).ready()

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I've simply created a container to test how to put text through AJAX in asp.net. This is how I coded:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WeeklySchedule.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="container" style="background-color: lightblue">
        <p id="Text"></p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Text").text("Hello World");
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Is there anything I've done wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The selector must be very specific. For example:

```
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <div class="container" style="background-color: lightblue">
        <p ID="something">Hi</p>
        <p ID="Text"></p>
    </div>

    <script scr="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".container #Text").text(function () {

            });
        });
    </script>
```

From the outer tag .container to the specific tag you want (#Text)

Answer (score 0):

You have used jQuery $. Have you included jQuery in your page?

Comment: If I add `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"` at the script tag, then it should be working right?

Comment: Right, buy in another script tag. Put it before the 
 <script type="text/javascript">
line

Comment: No, it still haven't  solved

Comment: It works if I put $("<tag>") instead of id and class